# Click on link using Beautifulsoup/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am trying to extract the prices and the names of the sellers which are displayed after clicking the View All Offers-link on [this website](https://www.noon.com/uae-en/iphone-11-with-facetime-black-128gb-4g-lte-international-specs/N29884715A/p?o=eaf72ceb0dd3bc9f/p?o=b478235d26032e5a).

The problem is that I can't find a link in the html source code for the View All Offers-button.

[image: webiste with View All Offers-Link]

Comment: You tagged your question with selenium, beautifulsoup and scrapy - which library are you actually using? And what exactly are you trying to achieve? The info from the View All Offers-link is stored in the class `.offersList`. If you are using scrapy and you are trying to extract the selling price from all offers for example, use `response.css('.offersList .sellingPrice .value::text').getall()` and you will receive `['2863.95', '2864.95', '2872.95', '3050.00', '2847.00', '2999.00']`.

Comment: I am using beautiful soup to get price and seller but i am not getting it from main page. write the following code now: 

`from requests import get`
`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`
`url = 'https://www.noon.com/uae-en/iphone-11-with-facetime-black-128gb-4g-lte-international-specs/N29884715A/p?o=eaf72ceb0dd3bc9f'`
`resp = get(url)`
`soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')`
`print(soup.css('.offersList .sellingPrice .value::text').getall())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution with beautifulsoup that gets all selling prices and seller names from the View All Offers-tab could look like this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

url = 'https://www.noon.com/uae-en/iphone-11-with-facetime-black-128gb-4g-lte-international-specs/N29884715A/p?o=eaf72ceb0dd3bc9f'
resp = get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, 'lxml')
for offer in soup.find_all("li", class_="item"):
    print(offer.find("span", class_="sellingPrice").find("span", class_="value").text)
    print(offer.find("div", class_="sellerDetails").strong.text)
```

A solution in Scrapy could look like that:

```py
import scrapy


class noonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "noon"
    start_urls = ['https://www.noon.com/uae-en/iphone-11-with-facetime-black-128gb-4g-lte-international-specs/N29884715A/p?o=eaf72ceb0dd3bc9f/p?o=b478235d26032e5a']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            'sellingPrice': response.css('.offersList .sellingPrice .value::text').getall(),
            'seller': response.css('.offersList .sellerDetails strong::text').getall(),
        }
```